# Is the structure of a crystalized protein the native one?

Tags: structural-biology, proteins, x-ray-diffraction

When one finds the 3D structure of a protein by crystalizing it and then making a X-ray experiment, how does one know that the geometrical configuration of the crystal is the same (or even close) to the structure the protein adopt in aqueous solution?

Comment: Well, it doesn't need to be, be it's still something. NMR is getting structures in solutions.

Comment: @Mithoron And they're doing fancy stuff with proteins NMR, but I don't see how they would get a whole configuration. That would be amazing.

Comment: @DGS Significant percent of protein structures was obtained with NMR not X-ray. http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/static.do?p=general_information/about_pdb/nature_of_3d_structural_data.html

Comment: @Mithoron And to think I have trouble assinging something that weighs around 500 g/mol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll use quotes from B. Rupp, *Biomolecular Crystallography* (p. 7-8) to answer.

Generally the structure is similar...

> Comparison of many nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) solution structure
>   ensembles with crystallographic structure has shown that the core
>   structure of protein molecules remains unchanged compared with the
>   solution state during crystallization. In addition, enzymes packed in
>   crystals even maintain biological activity.

with some parts not visible in the experiment...

> The maintenance of the core structure and of enzymatic function shows
>   that crystal structures are a very good approximation of the native
>   protein solution structure. Nonetheless, highly flexible or mobile
>   regions, frequently the amino- or carboxyl-termini of the protein chain or 
>   flexible loops connecting secondary structure elements, can be
>   poorly defined or even absent in the electron density and thus can be
>   modeled only with limited confidence.

but beware...

> In certain situation flexible and dynamic regions of a protein
>   molecule can be rigidly fixed in a specific conformation as a result
>   of crystal packing interactions. In most cases this represents just a
>   snapshot of one possible conformation out of many and it must be
>   understood that such a specific conformation may not locally represent
>   the protein structure in solution. A simple safeguard against
>   misinterpretations -- which is usually assignment of certain
>   biological relevance to regions where that is *de facto* not warranted --
>   is to display all neighboring, symmetry-related molecules in the crystal
>   structure and examine if any intermolecular interactions are
>   present that are a result of crystal packing. Such packing induced
>   artifacts can also hamper for example drug discovery by altering or
>   blocking binding sites and thus preventing an otherwise active
>   substance from binding.